# How does User Registration work while using an API Gateway

Tags: microservices, api-gateway, kong, konga

I was reading up about API Gateways (Kong) and I wanted to integrate it into my application. Every tutorial I've seen creates consumers for the services using Kong API or through a dashboard like Konga. I already have a user registration/auth service. How can the API Gateway replace that ? How should the user registration be changed so that Kong knows about it ? And how would login work because In all the examples I've seen the ApiKeys or JWT secrets are created in Kong ? Can any body shed some light on how this works in practice ?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion Kong is not supposed to replace a user registry / authentication service. However, it can help you enforce authentication.

There are several options of securing your APIs against unauthorized access. These include:

- API key: this type is used with the `key-auth` plugin and is not intended for authenticating users (meaning natural persons) but consumers (meaning other systems).
- JWT tokens: this type is used with the `jwt` plugin and is suitable for user authentication. Kong is responsible for validating the JWT tokens (by checking the signature and expiry of the self contained token). You can of course do further checks either with custom Kong plugins or within your upstream service.

So I think you shouldn't think of Kong as a replacement for your user service, but as a complement/addition which helps you enforcing security policies even before the request reaches your upstream service.